# Dynamic updating text file used for language translation in application using Objective C in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, file-handling, nsfilemanager

I have been working on an application which uses text files to dynamic translate strings according to the key value pair provided by service. I am unable to update that file as it is not writable, also file manager fails to delete that file i.e. it returns false when removeItematPath is called. How can it be updated?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to delete files from your Bundle, that's normal behavior.

Comment: can it be replaced?..or updated using file handling.

Comment: Why don't you copy that file from your bundle to NSDocumentDirectory and do your read/writes from there?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? There are a lot of potential solutions to your problem. Context is required to know what would be good in your case. E.g. are you using a specific system for translation (such as the built in `NSLocalizedString`)? Is there a reason you can't re-compile? How often are values expected to change?